# iOS - Duplicate symbols when added Firebase Messaging (conflict with Google Analytics)

Tags: ios, google-analytics, firebase, cocoapods, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to add Firebase Cloud Messaging to my project which has already other services from Google (like Analytics). I am using cocoapods and I added to my podfile:

```
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
```

I run `pod install` and everything looked good but when I am trying to build project I get many duplicate symbol errors:

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ACPGmpAudienceRoot in:
    .../Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpAudience.pb.o)
    .../Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpAudience.pb_d68254ec585824fa42de6de2f056cda0.o)
... more and more duplicate symbol errors ...
```

How can I fix it? Why with Messaging there is added Analytics library too? I don't need it. I tried Clean project and delete Derived data but for now without luck.

Comment: you should remove google analytics and use the Firebase Analytics now.

Comment: It's not the solution I was looking for. Is there other way?

Comment: Have you found the solution ?

Answer (score 4):

Update your Google/(Google analytics) pod version to 3.0 higher .
I was using version 2.0.4, I did `pod update` and the following pods were update:

- Installing Google 3.0.3 (was 2.0.4)
- Installing GoogleSignIn 4.0.0  (was 3.0.0)

After that I was able to use Google analytics with Firebase

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, one thing you can consider: If you use Google Tag Manager, you can integrate with Firebase Analytics, and use GTM to forward the event data to Google Analytics if you prefer to have app and web data together or want to use Google Analytics for some other reason.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same issue - an iOS app that is already using Google Analytics, but I want to add Firebase Messaging, just so the app can have a push notification capability.  I added "pod 'Firebase/Messaging'" to the Podfile, and had the same linking errors on compiling.

A lot of searching revealed this compiler setting: Your Target -> Build Settings - Apple LLVM 7.1 - Code Generation -> No Common Blocks - set it to 'Yes', like this:

[image: Build Settings]

On Xcode 7.3 it seems the default for that setting is 'No', bu on making that change all the linking errors went away and the app built without issues.

Comment: I have it set to No and I tried to change it but without luck. Still getting same errors. Did you change anything else?

Comment: Ok, yeah, sorry, I tried setting that value back to 'Yes', but I didn't get the linking errors to reocur, so now I'm not so sure.  I went from seeing the linking errors all the time, to never seeing them, but I'm not too sure what the critical change was.

Comment: I only have "pod 'Firebase/Messaging'" in my Podfile.  I don't think you need "pod 'Firebase'" if you only want to use the messaging part of Firebase.

Comment: I've Google Cloud Messaging in my project. And I want to use Firebase Analytics. Now I've pod the Firebase using pod 'Firebase/Analytics', but still the duplicate build error is there. :(

Comment: I remove "pod 'Firebase'" from my Podfile but I have still problem that FirebaseAnalytics is installed

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what to tell you - I can't pin the original cause down exactly - but it stopped being an issue for me, and hasn't been a problem since.  I don't know what changed to make the project link. Maybe try moving sections around in your Podfile - it seems likely to me that there's some issue with the way cocoapods is configuring the project.